# mongodb php: count the number of field in a set of documents

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter, aggregation-framework, codeigniter-3

I am using codeigniter with mongodb library
https://github.com/intekhabrizvi/Codeigniter-mongo-library

below is my collection "users". 
I want to count all the badges which has badge_slug = 100_club from users collection.

What I have tried is

```
$this->mongo_db->where(array('badges.badge_slug'=>"100_club"))->count('users');
```

but it only gives the number of users have 100_club no matter its more then one time.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57b83ae9faa76bac338b4579"),
"displayname" : "test",
"email" : "test@gmail.com",
"badges" : [
    {
        "awarded_at" : ISODate("2015-04-21T05:52:06Z"),
        "object_id" : "",
        "badge_slug" : "100_club"
    },
    {
        "awarded_at" : ISODate("2015-04-21T06:12:14Z"),
        "object_id" : "",
        "badge_slug" : "100_club"
    },
    {
        "awarded_at" : ISODate("2015-04-21T07:09:55Z"),
        "object_id" : "",
        "badge_slug" : "reader"
    }
]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57b83ae9faa76bac338b457a"),
    "displayname" : "test2",
    "email" : "test2@gmail.com",
    "badges" : [
        {
            "awarded_at" : ISODate("2015-04-21T06:44:20Z"),
            "object_id" : "",
            "badge_slug" : "100_club"
        }
    ]
}
```

Can you please let me know how can I get the total number of 100_club occurred in the users collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aggregation approach follows where you can use the **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter)** and **[`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size)** operators to get the count per document and then group all the documents to get the total count. This approach doesn't require using the **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** operator to flatten the badges array but works with MongoDB version 3.2 and greater:

**mongo shell**

```
var ops = [
    {
        "$project" {
            "count": {
                "$size": {
                    "$filter": {
                        "input": "$badges",
                        "as": "badge",
                        "cond": { "$eq": ["$$badge.badge_slug", "100_club"] }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "total": { "$sum": "$count" }
        }
    }
];
db.users.aggregate(ops);
```

**PHP**

```
$ops = array(
    array(
        "$project" => array(
            "count" => array(
                "$size" => array(
                    "$filter" => array(
                        "input" => "$badges",
                        "as" => "badge",
                        "cond" => array("$eq" => => array("$$badge.badge_slug", "100_club") )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        "$group" => array(
            "_id" => null,
            "total" => array( "$sum" => "$count" )
        )
    )
);
$this->mongo_db->aggregate("users", $ops);
```

---

For an approach that uses the **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** operator to flatten the badges array first before grouping, follow this example:

**mongo shell**

```
db.users.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "badges.badge_slug": "100_club" }
    { "$unwind": "$badges" },
    { "$match": { "badges.badge_slug": "100_club" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "total": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    }
])
```